# Add a canvas on the map that can pan and zoom along with it

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, mapcanvas

I want to know if it's possible to add a canvas on a ArcGIS map that can pan and zoom along with it.

The reason I ask that it's because we have different workflows where we have a lot of entities (+1000) that need to be refreshed at a regular interval (3-5 sec). These entities are SVG DOM element and the rendering performance is poor.

One solution we want to try to improve rendering performance is to add canvas on map and add these entities on it.

Is it possible? Do you have any idea/sample how to do that?

Comment: Do you mean like an overview map? (e.g. [Esri Sample](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=widget_overviewmap))

Comment: yes something like that

Comment: in the sample you provide, I would like to add a canvas layer where I can draw entities. I saw samples where you can pan/zoom on canvas, but I'm a little bit stuck with the implementation... Maybe someone has already did something like that before...

Comment: Right -- I know that [`overviewMap`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/overviewmap-amd.html) exists, but I've never done anything with it :)

Comment: Finally, we have something interesting with dojo to support canvas in ArcGIS map. I will post the solution as a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we've found something of promising. It is not well documented but you can set gfxRenderer to «canvas» on Dojo configuration and ESRI will load «magically» the entities on a canvas with panning/zooming/click support.

```
<script>  
  var dojoConfig = {   
    "gfxRenderer": "canvas",  
    "isDebug": true,  
    "parseOnLoad": true   
  };  
</script>
```

Reference:
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/43802